# Complex select based on two has_many associations

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have following models

Account

```
has_many :orders
has_many :account_brands, dependent: :destroy
has_many :brands, through: :account_brands
```

Brand

```
  has_many :account_brands, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :accounts, through: :account_brands
  has_many :orders
```

Order

```
belongs_to :account
belongs_to :brand
```

Now i want to select all accounts that does have order with the brand that not associated with the said account. I can do it through looping and checking each particular brand, but it's highly inefficient. Can't wrap my head around how to do it in one SQL call?

Just to clarify and reword:

I want all accounts that have order with the brand that is not currently associated with the account

```
Account1 have brands A,B,C    
Account2 have brands A,B,C


Account1 have order with the brand D -> want this account to be selected
Account2 have order with the brand C -> doesn't care about this one
```

Comment: can you please tell what you meant by 'said' account?

Comment: So from my understanding, is that you want all acounts which have orders for a brand?

Comment: sorry not my native language, just updated my question with the example

Comment: I have updated the answer. Please check

Comment: `SELECT * FROM accounts JOIN orders ON accounts.id = orders.account_id WHERE accounts.brand_id <> order.brand_id`, is that what you need in rails ?

Answer (score 0):

To find out accounts, which have orders for brands which are not associated with the specified account, try the following query,

```
Account.joins(:brands).joins("LEFT JOIN orders ON (orders.account_id = accounts.id AND orders.brand_id != brands.id)")
```